# how can i deal with ClassCastException in Java GUI?

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) e.getSource();
        if (isDragged) {
            if (rect.contains(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()))) {
                r1.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 100, 100);
                repaint();
                check();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i deal with ClassCastException in Java GUI?

I want to Drag My Rectangle and Check to Collision.
When I drag, an error code is generated.
I want to click on the source of the place into a rectangle and use it to fulfill the conditions and try the following conditions.

Comment: what is `r1`? what is the definition of `Rectangle`'s contains method?

Comment: r1 is Rectangle.
Like this, Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(10,10,50,50);

the definition of contains
    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return contains(p.x, p.y);
    }

Answer (score 0):

`e.getSource()` returns the component on which the event initially occured. In the case of `mouseDragged()` it is the component who is receiving the mouse press event. This component can't be casted to `Rectangle`.

The expression `new Point(e.getX(), e.getY())` can be written as `e.getPoint()`.